# iOS Swift Getting Lazy Map Collection Values

Tags: swift, dictionary, collections, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to get the value for "alert" but not having very much luck.

```
LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>, AnyHashable>(_base: [AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("google.c.a.ts"): 1475009164, AnyHashable("google.c.a.udt"): 0, AnyHashable("gcm.n.e"): 1, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "test message";
}, AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_id"): 9039575328704479116, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1475009164740581%df6f7f01df6f7f01], _transform: (Function))
```

This is the code is a using but it does not work correctly

```
if (userInfo["aps"] != nil) {
                    let msg = (userInfo["alert"] as? String)!
                    let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                    }))
                    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    completionHandler(.newData)
                }
```

I am trying to display a local notification with the message of the value alert.  Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What does "does not work correctly" mean? What does it do, and what do you expect it to do? And how is this `LazyMapCollection` related to the code below it?

Comment: I am trying to display the value for "alert" which is "test message" in the notification.   This line of code throws an exception let msg = (userInfo["alert"] as? String)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working solution

```
if (userInfo["aps"] != nil) {
                    if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary,
                        let alert = notification["alert"] as? String {
                        let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: alert, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                        }))
                        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        completionHandler(.newData)

                    }
                }
```